# what happens if I use a pointer and dont use the "&" symbol

Tags: c++, pointers

So I'm trying to understand passage by reference and I came across this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int var;
  int *ptr;
  int val;

  var = 3000;

  // take the address of var
  ptr = &var;

  // take the value available at ptr
  val = *ptr;
  cout << "Value of var :" << var << endl;
  cout << "Value of ptr :" << ptr << endl;
  cout << "Value of val :" << val << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The thing about the code is that I don't understand why we have to do `ptr = &var`. Since ptr is a pointer, shouldn't it already be pointing to the address of var? And also, what would happen if I just type `ptr = var` instead?

Comment: Have you tried it to find out?

Comment: When you assume C++ will "know" things, remember that C++ has a long, long history and back in the 1980s computers didn't have the capacity to do the forward thinking and intuition that you take for granted today. A lot of the standard built up around the principle of programmers having to express *exactly* what they intend. C++ does not really "do what you mean" like in other languages.

Comment: "Since ptr is a pointer souldn't it be already pointing to the adress of var." Just because someone is a doctor and I am sick, does not mean the doctor will cure me. " what woul happen if I just type "ptr = var" instead?" Well, what do you think the `&` means? (Hint: what does the comment say?)

Comment: `var` is the variable. `&var` is the address of the variable.  If you want to use the address of the variable , which one do you think would be right?

Comment: @OP `int main () {int  var; int x; double y; float z; double y2l; float z2; int  *ptr;` -- Given this, what should `ptr` magically point to without you telling it what to point to?

Comment: *so Im trying to understand passage by reference* -- Also, what the `&` means in this context is *not* refererences.  It means *address-of*, not *reference*.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `int *ptr;` doesn't store the address of anything at first. So if you tried to dereference the pointer without setting it to `&var`, your code will have undefined behavior. It might crash; it might output some garbage number, who knows...

By writing `ptr = &var`, you are telling c++ to set the `ptr` variable to the address of `var`. Once you've done this, now c++ is actually pointing to an integer variable and can be dereferenced with defined behavior. If you change `var = 12`, dereferencing ptr will result in 12.

If you typed `ptr=var`, you are telling c++ to set the `ptr` variable to the value of `var` which doesn't make sense. The compiler knows this and will spit out an error `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’`

Answer (score 2):

> Since `ptr` is a pointer, shouldn't it already be pointing to the address of `var`?

No, just because `ptr` is a pointer it will not be autmatically pointing to `var`. Imagine if you many `int` variables like `var` then how will the compiler know which one to point to.

Also, if you write `int *ptr;` then the pointer `ptr` is **uninitialized** meaning it has indeterminate value. If you were to now dereference this uninitialized pointer then the program will have undefined behavior.

---

> what would happen if I just type `ptr = var` instead?

You can't because it is illegal to assign an `int` *variable* to a pointer, even if the variable’s value happens to be `0`. But note that you can use the integer *literal* `0` to initialize `ptr`. This is because `0` is also a null pointer constant that converts to any pointer type.

```
int *ptr; //ptr is uninitialized and if you were to dereference ptr, it will be undefined behavior
ptr = 0;  //VALID because 0 is a null pointer constant 

int var = 0;
ptr = var;  //INVALID
```